# Typecast string to boolean in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, marklogic, xsd-validation

I have a source XML like:

```
<source>
  <a>NONE</a>
  <b>2008-04-10</b>
</source>
```

I transform the source XML to a target using XSLT

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0">
<target>
  <d>
    <xsl:value-of select="//source/a"/>
  </d>
  <e>
    <xsl:value-of select="//source/b"/>
  </e>
</target>
```

My XSD contains a definition such that the element 'd' must be boolean and 'e' must be a date. But while validating the transformed XML against the XSD using stylus studio I get an error saying

1. value 'NONE' is invalid boolean
2. missing 'T' separator in dateTime value '2008-04-10'

How should the data be typecasted in the XSLT in this case to resolve the errors? Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think an XSD will try coerce a value before validating its type. First, `<xsl:value-of>` returns a string, so for this example you could use `<xsl:sequence>` instead, which will return the type of the expression.

Assuming the XSD defines `<d>` as a boolean, you could cast as boolean in the XSLT: `<xsl:sequence select="//source/a/xs:boolean(.)">` However, you may run into problems if that expression returns a squence and the XSD is only expecting a singleton value.

Assuming the XSD defines `<e>` as `xs:dateTime`, then you will need to do more work to get there, since `2008-04-10` isn't a [valid xs:dateTime](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime) (which would look something like `2015-05-01T15:29:04.579528-05:00`). MarkLogic has a function called `xdmp:parse-dateTime`, that will convert a "pretty printed" time into a valid `xs:dateTime`. Assuming you are using MarkLogic to run the XSLT, you could coerce that value like this: `<xsl:sequence select="//source/b/xdmp:parse-dateTime('[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]', .)">`. The same issue with sequences applies here.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative method to what wst mentioned for the boolean portion, you could change

```
<xsl:value-of select="//source/a"/>
```

to

```
<xsl:variable name="lowertrue" select="true" />
<xsl:variable name="uppertrue" select = "TRUE" />
<xsl:value-of select="(translate(/source/a, $uppertrue, $lowertrue) = 'true') or (/source/a = '1')"/>
```

which would give you a bit more control over what you interpret as true (you could add additional or clauses in there to check for other possible values you would consider true).  What I've provided here would check for "true" in any casing ("TRUE", "True", "TrUE", etc...) or for the value 1.

Answer (score 0):

The lexical space for boolean values in XSD is `true`, `false`, `1` and `0`.  Anything else must be translated to one of those exact 4 values in order to be a valid boolean value.  You can use the following expression for instance (depends on the details of your input language):

```
if ( a eq 'NONE' ) then 'false' else 'true'
```

You can also simply use the following (assuming that `a` is not the empty sequence, the result of that XPath expression is a boolean value, which in turn will be serialized into one of the 4 lexical representations for booleans, depending on the value of the expression):

```
a ne 'NONE'
```

As per your second question, wst is right, you do not have a valid `xs:date`, you have a `xs:dateTime`.  So either you have to change the type in the schema (to be a date-time) or you adapt the value to be a date-time instead of a date (you will have to decide what time to use, e.g. noon or midnight).